# css "word break" is not working when I use Korean

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, word-break

I want to line break the  tag with word.  I used various css but it isn't working.
I used "word-break: break-word" , "word-wrap:break-word", and "overflow-wrap: break-word".
All of them not working.
I want to know why.
When I put Korean in the span tag, "word break" is not working. but when I put English in the span tag, It is working.
This is React project.
Thank you for helping me :)

```
<td style={{ position: 'relative'}}>
  <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
    <span style={{ display: 'inline-block', width: '6.25rem', whiteSpace: 'normal', wordBreak: 'break-word'}}>유음의 단순화</span>
    </div>
</div>
```